# Static class with unique id per request

Tags: .net, scope, serilog

I want to achieve something similar (but much simpler) like Serilog sinks without using DI explicitly.

It's easy to do with DI you just have to register service as scoped and just create id when object is initialized.

But how to achieve that with a static class? It's somehow possible because .NET Serilog team did that.

If you want to use their logger you can simply initialize it:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Filter.ByExcluding(c => c.Properties.Any(p => p.Value.ToString().Contains("swagger")))
    .Filter.ByExcluding(c => c.Properties.Any(p => p.Value.ToString().Contains("liveness")))
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console(new ElasticLogFormatter())
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(elasticConfiguration.Url))
    {
        AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
        AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv6,
        IndexFormat = elasticConfiguration.Index,
        CustomFormatter = new ElasticLogFormatter()
    })
    .CreateLogger();
```

And whenever you use

```cs
Log.Information("message");
```

it contains a unique request id within a single request despite where you use this (controller, service, db context - they all share the same id).

I've found [their code](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) on GitHub, but with that, it still remains a struggle to find where and how they achieved that.

Comment: Why do you think that the Serilog team is not relying on the DI infrastructure? The fact that the logger itself is static does not mean that somewhere in the middle DI is not used to setup context holding the enrich data.

Comment: I wasn't specific. Your're right the probably does. But how to achive that. Because whenever i get service using scopeFactory it works partly because id is assigned per method called not a scope.

Comment: If you look at the code you linked to the [Information](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/635667b054f2d699ebcecb8acfe7816da099ca80/src/Serilog/Log.cs#L564) method you indicate delegates to the [Write](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/635667b054f2d699ebcecb8acfe7816da099ca80/src/Serilog/Log.cs#L116) method. That used the Log.Logger which you set via your initialization code. So the Logger is just held statically and used by the static methods.